# Reputation Error on Main Reputation Site

Tags: bug, reputation

When looking at [PA.SE's main reputation](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/708/quarter/proofassistants), I can see that Namdak Tonpa's quarterly reputation is higher than the total reputation. How is this possible? Which one is erroneous?

[image]

Comment: Relevant MSE posts: [Discrepancy in Stats for StackOverflow's Top Users by Week, Month, Quarter, or Year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260052/282094), [Mismatch between the top users in the Stack Exchange league and period wise report pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337643/282094)